# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' for pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, integer

**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'**

Data is :

```
print(df)


    Content               Page no
0   My name is mark       3
1   My name is jeff       3
2   My name is bill       3
```

The code is :

```
df['doc_len'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda words: len(words.split()))
```

The error it's returning is :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7d2f1de16b3d> in <module>
----> 1 df['doc_len'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda words: len(words.split()))

~\t5\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-26-7d2f1de16b3d> in <lambda>(words)
----> 1 df['doc_len'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda words: len(words.split()))

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**The Content column is object type and it's returning int object has no attribute split**

Comment: try `df['Content'].str.split().apply(len)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

via `str.split()` and `str.len()`:

```
df['doc_len']=df['Content'].str.split().str.len()
```

**OR**

via `str.count()` and then add 1:

```
df['doc_len']=df['Content'].str.count(' ')+1
```

Comment: Some developers generally prefer counting the number of empty spaces `' '`, so I think second solution is better